# Can you dynamically render pure HTML and a custom component in one React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

What I want is

```js
var dynamicTagProps1 = {
  Tag: "span",
  elementAttrs: {
    "aria-label": "test",
    "role": "test"
  }
} as IDynamicTagComponentProps;

var dynamicTagProps2 = {
  Tag: "div",
  elementAttrs: {
    "aria-label": "test2",
    "role": "test2"
  }
} as IDynamicTagComponentProps;

var dynamicTagProps3 = {
  Tag: "MyCustomComp",
  elementAttrs: {
    "aria-label": "test3",
    "role": "test3"
    }
} as IDynamicTagComponentProps;

<body>
  <DynamicTagComponent {...dynamicTagProps1} />
</body>

=>
<body>
  <span aria-label='test' role='test' />
</body>

<body>
  <div aria-label='test2' role='test2' />
</body>

<body>
  <MyCustomComp aria-label='test3' role='test3' />
</body>
```

I know it is possible to dynamically load pure HTML elements in React, something like:

```js
export interface IDynamicTagComponentProps {
  Tag: string;
  elementAttrs: Record<string, string>;
}

export function DynamicTagComponent(props: IDynamicTagComponentProps) {
  var moreAttr = props.elementAttrs;
  return React.createElement(props.Tag, { ...moreAttr }, null);
}
```

But for `React.createElement`, it will be different for a pure HTML element and React component.

```js
React.createElement('div')
React.createElement(MyCustomComp)
```

So is it possible to dynamic render pure HTML tag and `React.Component` in one component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can make dynamic components in React. Simply pass the tag you was as a prop to the component:

```js
function Dynamic({
  as = 'div',
  props,
  children
}) {
  const Tag = as;
  return <Tag {...props}>{children}</Tag>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dynamic as={'p'} props={{'aria-label': 'test'}}>A dynamic component</Dynamic>,           document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```